# Include javascript array in params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameters

The user can click elements on my page. Their names are filled into a javascript array via an onclick-event. I want to pass this array as params in my url to the next page. How do I include a javascript array in the ruby <%= %>?

I read to use ajax for this. As my javascript skills are very minor, I am wondering if there is an easy fix for my problem.

```
    <div class="new-content">
      <div class="newmap-cards">
        <% @companies.each do |company|%>
           <% if company.photo.present? %>
          <button class="newmap-card" value=<%=company.name%> style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),
         url('<%= cl_image_path company.photo, height: 300, width: 400, crop: :fit %>')">
            <p><%= company.name %></p>
          </button>
        <% else %>
        <button class="newmap-card" value=<%=company.name%> >
            <p><%= company.name %></p>
          </button>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div
      id="map"
      data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>">
      </div>

      <%= button_to "", new_user_registration_path, method: :get, class: "student-select-card", params: { vacancy_id: params[:vacancy_id], job_category: params[:job_category], jobs_interested: "${var n}" } %>

    </div>

<script>
  var n = [];

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        var val = event.target.value;
        n.push(val);
        console.log(n);      //these console.log are tests
        console.log(ret);
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = val;
    }
});

</script>
```

So this part in my code is definitely wrong: jobs_interested: "${var n}"

But how can I do that instead?

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: yes i am using jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below based on your business logic, When user click on next page collect all checked element as array and pass it in ajax request.

```
$(document).on('change', 'id or class of your html element', function(evt) {
      return $.ajax('Path of your action', {
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
              data: pass array of values here
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             // your business logic
            }
          });
});
```

Comment: i might be a bit slow here. But what does business logic here means in this example?

Comment: what you want to do when your ajax request is completed

Comment: I want to forward the user to the users/sign_up page. With the new params. Could you make your example more specific for me? thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Sabrina did you sorted out your problem?

Comment: I did not. I am afraid understand too little of javascript to understand your answer.

Comment: if you would that would be of great help!

Comment: Yes. i would love to help you. what will be your new params? from where you get those params?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way can be like this-

Chnage button as -

```
<%= button_to "", new_user_registration_path(vacancy_id: params[:vacancy_id], job_category: params[:job_category]), method: :get, class: "student-select-card" %>
```

Javascript code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var n = [];
  document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
      var val = event.target.value;
      n.push(val);
      console.log(n);      //these console.log are tests
      console.log(ret);
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = val;
      // Get existing path of button
      var existingPath = document.getElementsByClassName("student-select-card").getAttribute("href");
      // Set new path and pass paramter jobs_interested
      document.getElementsByClassName("student-select-card").setAttribute("href", existingPath + "&jobs_interested="+n);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Ps, I'm not sure if your existing cod is working already, have just modified and added a way to pass javascript variable with existing URL.
Hopefully, this should help you.

Comment: this looks like an easy solution. But i get the following error when i hit the button:  No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up".   How do I tell him to do a GET request instead?

Comment: @Sabrina sorry for inconvenience can you please show me the error log?

Comment: Started POST "/users/sign_up?job_category=Marketing+%26+Design&vacancy_id=general+application" for ::1 at 2019-08-02 15:53:33 +0200
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"):

Comment: shouldn't it be a get request instead of a post request?

Comment: Also it does not look like he actually attached the array to the url :(

Comment: @sabrina Ah i forgot that `button_to` internally creates a form and form submission is by by default `post` instead of get so i here by I would suggest you to add `method: :get` or you can use `link_to` instead of `button_to`. Aside of that is you are sure about that you correctly forming the `n` array using JavaScript then it will definitely will be passed with the url.  :)  hopefully that make sense.

Comment: changing it to link_to definitely worked. But it is not sending the "&jobs_interested=" in the url. When I open google console and check console.log(n) the javascript works. Meaning that the array is filled with the names. Seems like the href is not being changed. any idea why that is?

Comment: @Sabrina Can you inspect wheather path is chaining or not?

Comment: path is not changing at all.